# Basic type-driven ppx rewriting

Tags: ocaml, metaprogramming

I'm writing my first ppx extension. The idea is to support a polymorphic `print` function, similar to `show` in Haskell.

(I'm aware that other more robust solutions exist, but I wish to learn more about how this works.)

The approach I've taken is very similar to the method described [here](http://whitequark.org/blog/2014/04/16/a-guide-to-extension-points-in-ocaml/): I have a mapper which looks for `%[print <expr>]` tags, then replaces them with a string representation of `<expr>`. For example,

```
[%print 1] ==> string_of_int 1
[%print "aksljd"] ==> "aksljd"
```

This works fine for constant expressions, but I want to support any arbitrary expression in place of `<expr>`. It should just wrap them with a printer of the final type.

My current approach is to use `Typecore.type_expression` to turn a `Parsetree.expression` into a `Typedtree.expression`, then match on the `exp_type` field of the `Typedtree.expression` and determine what to replace the whole expression with. For example, for a type `type test = A of int | B of string`, I would replace `[%print A 1]` with `show_test (A 1)` there (`show_test` must be present by convention).

This doesn't work because `Typecore.type_expression` takes a type environment as an argument, and I can't get the 'current type environment' at the point of rewriting, because type-checking hasn't even been performed then... `[%print 1 + 1]` with `Typecore.type_expression Env.empty` causes `Unbound value +`, as it should.

Does anyone have a solution to this? If I'm heading in the wrong direction entirely, feel free to point this out. :p

Comment: What is the intended meaning of this: `let f x = [%print x]`?

Comment: Good point. Yes, polymorphism wouldn't work with this. I haven't thought everything out completely, this is just a naive first attempt to learn ppx :)

Comment: Given this information, how would an equivalent function `print :: Show a => a -> String` that just calls `show` on its argument work in Haskell? After this passes typechecking, will the compiler inline it, then replace every instance of `show` with its statically-known implementation?

Comment: No problem. I am not sure from your question – are you aware that this also wouldn't work in Haskell, for the same reason (among others)? What Haskell does is effectively pass a hidden "module" (type class instance) that implements show for some types.

Comment: You can think of `Show a =>` as an OCaml first-class module being passed, with a signature like this `sig type t = a val to_string : a -> string end`. When you use `to_string` on `a`, Haskell selects it from this "module".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A summary of the discussion in comments: `show` in Haskell doesn't work like this (and can't). `Show a =>` in Haskell would be translated to an explicit module argument in OCaml. That module would have a value with signature like `print : a -> string`. Haskell infers this module argument by finding an instance of `Show` for `a` that you (or libraries) have declared, but in OCaml you would have to pass the module manually. Declaring the `Show` instance in Haskell is analogous to instantiating a functor in OCaml.

In both Haskell and OCaml, preprocessing expressions as in the question would have dubious meaning in cases such as:

```
let f x = [%print x]
```

If `f : 'a -> string` (i.e. no Haskell type class instance is available and no OCaml module is being passed).

To make it more complete, many other ppx rewriters that analyze types generate code from type definitions or declarations, not from expressions.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is basically not supported with a ppx. As you noted, a ppx is after parsing, type checking is not done yet.
It's quite hard to type check arbitrary expressions due to the current architecture of the compiler.

You can read [this](https://bitbucket.org/camlspotter/compiler-libs-hack) if you want to hack your way through. :)
The author will do a presentation about it at the ocaml workshop in 2 weeks too, there should be a video of that.

Comment: I don't think it's just only not supported by ppx. I think it doesn't have sensible semantics in OCaml to begin with, unless the asker puts some constraints on when `%print` can be used. And it's not how it works in Haskell, either.

Comment: I see... In that case, what are the limits of compile-time metaprogramming which depends on types? I've seen some awesome solutions like ppx_implicits and ppx_deriving which seem to depend on types, but I haven't yet grokked the distinction between what can be statically known and what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: Note that those go on type definitions (sometimes declarations), not on expressions. Especially at a concrete monomorphic type definition, you have the type's structure available and there is nothing to infer and no polymorphism to worry about. In case of abstract or polymorphic types the generated values "delegate" some structure or processing to other values. The last statement is kind of hand-wavy because I am running out of comment space. Perhaps you should ask a new question? :)

Comment: @antron : that is true if you are talking about the specific issue in this question (implement a typeclass feature). However, I'm answering the general question "How do get typing informations in a ppx".

Comment: @user1953221 ppx_deriving doesn't rely on typing at all, only on the *syntactic* description of types.

Answer (score 2):

People have already answered in some extent... I hope my answer may add something.

PPX is preprocessing of *untyped* ASTs.  It is supposed to be used for AST transformation without knowledge of the typing of the inputs.

`ppx_deriving` and some other ppx preprocessors auto-generate codes for each type definitions and constructors.  They do really cool things but they work purely inside the untyped layer: they just make use of syntactic structure of type definitions. For type dependent behaviour, you need to give the type information explicitly in the untyped AST: `[%derive.show: (int * int) list] [(1,2); (3,4); (5,6)]`.  `[%derive.show] [(1,2); (3,4); (5,6)]` does not work.

Thus, PPX's I/O are untyped, but it is not limited to be untyped inside it.  You can do whatever typing you like.  One typical example is to feed the untyped input to OCaml typing checker and obtain a *typed* AST, then use the obtained typing information for your purpose.  The required tools for this typeful PPX are already in our hands: `ppx_tools` for general PPX tools, `compiler-libs` for typing by OCaml type checker and the preprocessing and `untypeast.ml` to make the result back to an untyped AST.  The link (https://bitbucket.org/camlspotter/compiler-libs-hack) @Drup has pointed out explains how to use them.  It was written before PPX came out, but in PPX what you do is pretty the same, and I have also added a small section for PPX to the article.

Only one downside of the typeful PPX is that it cannot be used with REPL. PPX processes compilation units one by one, and tranferring information between each unit processing is limited.  In REPL, a compilation unit is a toplevel phrase, and to work correctly, typeful PPX must keep the type environment over the toplevel phrases, which is too huge.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I've read your compiler hack article several times and gone over the source code for implicits :)